# Authentication with Dovecot, SHA512, and salts

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have a database that has a username, password, and password salt in it. The password is hashed using SHA512.

The data in my users database looks like this:

user = testuser

password_hash = 4acf9dc364843d1adfadfadf42de7d5707b791cc3ee8a2013f15efa8bdb

password_salt = QYhZ47zsQA=

I'm trying to authenticate to this database using dovecot sql authentication and SSHA512. I've turned authentication debugs on and I see this in mail.log:

```
dovecot: auth-worker(8603): Debug: sql(testuser,22.22.22.22): query: SELECT username as user, password_hash as password, password_salt as salt FROM users WHERE username='testuser';
dovecot: auth-worker(8603): sql(testuser,22.22.22.22): Password mismatch
dovecot: auth-worker(8603): Debug: sql(testuser,22.22.22.22): SSHA512(testpassword) != '4acf9dc364843d1adfadfadf42de7d5707b791cc3ee8a2013f15efa8bdb'
dovecot: auth: Debug: client passdb out: FAIL#0111#011user=testuser#011salt=QYhZ47zsQA=
dovecot: auth: Debug: client in:   AUTH#0112#011PLAIN#011service=imap#011secured#011session=rZmPoRYOagBJ3Ukh#011lip=33.33.33.33#01    1rip=22.22.22.22#011lport=993#011rport=53098#011resp=AHJpY2hlZQBjY2NwdGFtdDNtcA== (previous base64 data may contain sensitive data)
dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 2 attempts in 8 secs): user=<testuser>, method=PLAIN, rip=22.22.22.22, lip=33.33.33.33, TLS, session=<rZmPoRYOagBJ3Ukh>
```

I've also tried to do an auth test which fails too:

```
$ sudo doveadm auth test testuser testpassword
passdb: richee auth failed
extra fields:
  user=testuser
  salt=QYhZ47zsQA=
```

Unfortunately the [dovecot documentation](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Authentication/PasswordSchemes) doesn't cover exactly how to authenticate against salted hashes. I feel like I need to tell dovecot that my password hash is hex Salted SHA512 and my salt is 8 bytes base64. However I have no idea how to tell dovecot to use the salt. How can I use salts when authenticating dovecot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL-lookup password, dovecot has additional documentation [in here](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/SQL). For additional info you can read a thread on SO: [How to securely generate SSHA256 or SSHA512 hashes in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6713521/3604386). *In this answer I assume that you use MySQL for database.*

In order to matching dovecot auth scheme and your custom auth scheme, one of the method is your query must be returned `password` field that contain

> {SSHA512.HEX}**HashofPasswordandSaltinHEXformat**SaltinHEXformattoo

With string manipulation from SQL, we can construct a query like this

```
SELECT CONCAT("{SSHA512.HEX}", `hex_password`, HEX(FROM_BASE64(`salt`))) AS password FROM mytable WHERE userid = '%u'
```

Put above query to `password_query` parameter in dovecot-sql configuration file.

In the query above, we construct the special string via [SQL concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat). Of course because you have different format for salt and hash, then we must convert it by [base-64 decoding](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_from-base64) then [hex-encoding](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_hex).

---

Looks like the discussion here has been reblogged on [this page](http://www.tunnelsup.com/using-salted-sha-hashes-with-dovecot-authentication/) with more complete and comprehensive information.

Comment: This helps a lot but it still doesn't work. I've changed both my password and salt to hex. My errors look like this:
http://pastebin.com/g9BumKDj

Comment: Hi @TomFreezers, thanks for clarifying the answer. From the pastebin I have: (1) your `password` field was 128 bytes, (2) SHA512 hash always 64 bytes, so (3) your salt has 64 bytes-length. Are these true?

Comment: Yes in this case my salt is "5db034e27bda3045ef9e6057eb4799ea9c05d35c6a3b361697b20689ce44b16d". I'm using ruby to create the password hash and that function looks like this:
`salt = SecureRandom.hex(32)`
`hash = Digest::SHA512.hexdigest(password+salt)`
I've also confirmed that my authentication works if I use SHA512 without a salt by changing both the way the password is hashed and the way dovecot expects it to be.

Comment: It must be the way ruby is creating the hash. I've tried this with python and it works perfect. The python script I used was https://gist.github.com/garrettreid/8329796